# Encoding automatically in Postman

Tags: postman

i have an uri that ends in something like this

**...headfields=id,id^name**

i was using the encodeURIComponent(Right click on the uri) to replace that "^" by "%5E" and works fine.

But my question is, can this be automatic in postman?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

url encoding is done automatically you don't have to explicitly do that

[image]

**Note for query parameters if you type in special character with special meaning in the url then it will not encode it , if you give it in params then it will**

usecase 1 : typing in special characters

[image]

usecase2 :  giving it in params

[image]

### you can also encode in prerequest script as :

```
pm.request.url=encodeURI(pm.variables.replaceIn(pm.request.url))
```

Comment: Thanks! setting in the params solved all!